# Protractor: Using a where clause with a collection of elements

Tags: javascript, testing, protractor, automated-tests

I want to return the child `div`s closest to the parent of an element.

**HTML**

```
<div id='Parent'>
  <div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Protractor**

```
var parent = element(by.id('Parent'));
var topChildren = parent.all(by.tagName('div')).then(elem => [elem[0], elem[1]]); //this doesn't work.
```

I know the logic here might be wrong (would the top two elements really be the top children?) but I don't think this is even returning an array of elements. For instance, `topChildren.getAttribute('class')` throws a `topChildren.getAttribute is not a function` so it doesn't even see the return as a collection of elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want the direct children only (non-recursive search), you cannot use `by.tagName()` - it acts in a recursive way and there is no way to change that. I would solve it via a ["CSS selector"](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.By.css) and the [`>` direct parent-child relationship selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors):

```
var topChildren = $$("#Parent > div");
```

`$$` here is a [shortcut](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.$$) to `element.all(by.css())`.

---

Note that in this case you would have to have the `#Parent` part at the beginning since CSS selectors require to have a parent part in the `parent > children`-like selectors. In other words, you *cannot do*:

```
var parent = element(by.id('Parent'));
var topChildren = parent.$$("> div");  // <- would fail
```

If you need to have the `parent` element defined separately, then the `by.xpath()` would help:

```
var parent = element(by.id('Parent'));
var topChildren = parent.all(by.xpath(("./div"));
```